# keep saved state of view controller in SWRevealController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealController` in my app.I have one `MainController` as "HOME" which is shown when app launches. Now I have `textfield` & other controls on that screen. When i switch to another screen & come back to "Home" then all data on "Home" screen is gone then. It does not show any data there.I want to keep it's state saved. Now i want to keep that view controller in stack so that when i come back to this `viewcontroller` it remains in stack & other view controller are just popped out.Please explain how can i do that?

I am using below code for this.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"home" sender:cell];
        [cell setSelected:YES];
    }

    else if(indexPath.row==1)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"settings" sender:cell];
    }

    else if(indexPath.row==2)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"help" sender:cell];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row==3)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@“about” sender:cell];
    }

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Segue");
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UINavigationController *destViewController = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.title = [[titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] capitalizedString];
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"settings"])
    {
        self.revealViewController.navigationItem.title = @"settings";

    }
    else  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"help"])
    {
        self.revealViewController.navigationItem.title = @"help";
    }
    else  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"about"])
    {
        self.revealViewController.navigationItem.title = @"about";
    }

    if([segue isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]])
    {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {
            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];



        };

    }

  }
```

EDIT:

It tried below code & it is working in case i switch between "Home" & other screens twice.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        if(objMainController != nil)
        {
            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[objMainController] animated: NO ];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"home" sender:cell];
            [cell setSelected:YES];
        }

    }
    else if(indexPath.row==1)
    {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"settings" sender:cell];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row==2)
    {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"help" sender:cell];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row==3)
    {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:cell];
    }


}
```

**in prepareforsegue**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Segue");
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UINavigationController *destViewController = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.title = [[titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] capitalizedString];
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"settings"])
    {
        self.revealViewController.navigationItem.title = @"settings";

    }
    else  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"about"])
    {
        self.revealViewController.navigationItem.title = @"about";
    }
    else  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"help"])
    {
        self.revealViewController.navigationItem.title = @"help";
    }


    if([segue isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]])
    {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {
            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"home"])
            {
                objMainController = (MainViewController*)destViewController;
                self.revealViewController.navigationItem.title = @"home";
                [navController setViewControllers: @[objMainController] animated: NO ];
            }
            else
            {
                [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];

            }

            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        };

    }

  }
```

Comment: it means your view controller is initiize the memory new in stack

Comment: so in here u need to include any one type of database

Comment: i don't want to use database.Beacuase this will take a lot of efforts & time to save state.I would want if any how i can save viewcontroller in stack

Comment: in here you can't , the reason are u used the push on navigation, if it is pop your previous data will be available

Comment: tell me a way out please. i am stuck

Comment: take  the visible view controllers in stack , then check your particular vc in present in stack use pop else use push

Comment: can you give me code with reference to my current code implemented

Comment: sorry bro , I don't know your project flow, so that the reason i can't give the code related to your question'

Comment: bro SWL is the another Root Controller in our app, so I don't know the exact flow

Comment: It is the same flow as you will have in any navigation drawer.You have items in navigation menu & on click of each menu you will be redirected to different view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you perform a segue, a new `UIViewController` instance is created for you inside `destinationViewController` and you need to keep a reference to this once it is created (very first time).

#### Step #1

Keep a reference to all the `UIViewController` instances you need to keep state saved for-

```
SettingsViewController* objSettingsVC;
```

#### Step #2

Don't perform a segue if the instance for the screen you need to navigate to has been created earlier-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if(objSettingsVC != nil)
        {
            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[objSettingsVC] animated: NO ];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"settings" sender:cell];
        }
    }
}
```

#### Step #3

Keep the `UIViewController` instance in a variable to later refer to it as soon as it's created for the first time inside `prepareForSegue:` -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UINavigationController* destViewController = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"settings"])
    {
        objSettingsVC = (SettingsViewController*)destViewController;
        self.revealViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Settings";
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

### UPDATE:

As discussed below in the comments, you also need to keep the `initialViewController` instance in a variable. Here's how you can do it.

#### AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *objMainController;


@end
```

#### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     appDelegate.objMainController = self;
 }


 @end
```

This isn't a very good approach, but it will get you going. Your AppDelegate shouldn't be a part of all this navigation logic, you should keep this in a separate object responsible for your app navigation. Perhaps your `SideTableViewController` in your case.

Comment: It is keeping its state alive but only if i go to another viewcontroller & then i come back to viewcontroller from next time it will keep the state.

Comment: Isn't this how it should be? Not sure what you need. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: See when i launch app by default it shows "Home" screen.I have few labels & other UI controls.I set their value from buttons on home screen.So Now when i go to "Settings".I lost the data on "Home" screen all labels got their default values so i tried your approach.But what happens is for first time when i go to "Settings" & then i come back to "Home" all data lost but when i again repeat above steps then it works fine.Please check my edited answer

Comment: Problem is when first time your app is showing `MainViewController` instance, you are not keeping it inside `objMainController` variable. After you perform the segue once, you are keeping the instance in the supposed variable. You need to make sure you populate `objMainController` the very first time your app launches with default screen. And you're good to go!

Comment: Yes you are right.I tried to keep the value in variable but it shows me black screen.i tried this way but didn't work.
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    objMainController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];

Comment: issue is here that also i have more screens before i have SWrevealViewController so i can't set MainViewControlelr as root view controller.

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
             UINavigationController *ppc = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen"];
             [self presentViewController:ppc animated:true completion:nil];

Comment: Wherever you are pushing/presenting the **MainViewController** instance for the first time, you should populate the variable you will need later.

Comment: I declared "objMainCAontroller" variable inside "SideTableViewController" where i wrote all code for switching items in drawer.But for going to MainController i wrote code in RegisterViewConttoller so i tried below code but it does not work either



ViewController *ppc = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen"];
             SideTableTableViewController *test=[[SideTableTableViewController alloc]init];
             test.objMainController=(MainViewController*)ppc;
             [self presentViewController:ppc animated:true completion:nil];

Comment: Perhaps you need to add a property in **AppDelegate** for **objMainController** and populate it as soon as **MainViewContoller** loads the first time i.e. inside **viewDidLoad** in **MainViewController**

Comment: can you provide me code for that.I am stuck on this more than a week

Comment: Updates the answer. Please see if this fixes your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me.I would accept your answer for current question.But still i have one issue.

Comment: I think this answer solves the question completely. Bounty? If you have another question, let's open another question.

Comment: It's asking to reward bounty after 8 hours.Don't worry i will award bounty to you.Meanwhile i ask another question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115494/discussion-between-tarun-tyagi-and-deepak-kumar).

Comment: you got bounty bro

Comment: Thanks @deepakkumar Appreciate it.